# White empty space under content and above footer

Tags: html, css, wordpress, footer

I have this massive space of empty space under my content, and I can't seem to find where it is comping from. I must stress that I am not very experienced in code, I am using WordPress and a child theme and I spend a big chunk of time just trying to locate files from the parent theme and finding out where to do adjustments. So please answer as foolproof as possible.

I really hope anyone can help me!

http://marthapukallus.com/

[Example of the problem: Massive white space under content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhABY.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is your culprit?

```
.site {
    padding: 90px 20px;
    padding: 9rem 2rem;
}
```

Comment: It's not :). It's the `.gallery`

Comment: Please avoid answering low-quality questions. Stackoverflow has some rules which you are supposed to read before any activity on the site

Answer (score 0):

Your culprit is this line:

`<ul class="gallery gallery-animated">  <!--    --></ul>`

When removing it, the whitespace vanishes.
More specifiically:

```
.gallery {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    height: 100%; // This one removes the whitespace.
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Comment: Please avoid answering low-quality questions. Stackoverflow has some rules which you are supposed to read before any activity on the site

Comment: @Trix It'd like to disagree with the low quality, OP has put *some* effort into this question, and finding the actual problem here was not  obvious at all, especially if you have little knowledge of the subject.

Answer (score 0):

```
.gallery {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```